# Plotly express line chart mark specific points and retain hover data

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Consider the following example dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': list(range(1000, 2000)),
    'y1': np.random.randn(1000, ),
    'y2': 1 + np.random.randn(1000, )
})
```

Now I want to sort the dataframe by 'y1' in descending order and plot x vs y1. While showing id and y2 as hover data.

```py
from plotly import express as px

df = df.sort_values('y1', ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
df['x'] = df.index
fig = px.line(df, x='x', y='y1', hover_data=['id', 'y2'])
```

Now I want to mark 3 points on the x axis (say 100, 200, 300) as special and add markers only to those points

This is what I tried:

```py
from plotly import graph_objects as go

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[100, 200, 300],
        y=[df.at[100, 'y1'], df.at[200, 'y1'], df.at[300, 'y1']],
        mode='markers',
        name='Ground Truth'
    )
)
```

But this makes it so that when I hover at the marked points of the form `(x_special, y1(x_special))` the hover_data from  the dataframe is lost, I can no longer see the `id, y2` information for these points.

How do I mark only these special points with markers and still retain the hover data information from the dataframe.

I would also be okay if anyone has an alternative/better way of showing that certain x values are special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- have simulated data that matches your question.  Additionally picked **Ground truth** markers in a random way
- simple case of setting **hoverinfo**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# generate some data...
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "y1": np.random.uniform(1, 5, 50),
        "id": np.random.randint(1, 4, 50),
        "y2": np.random.uniform(5, 7, 50),
    }
)
df = df.sort_values("y1", ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
df["x"] = df.index
fig = px.line(df, x="x", y="y1", hover_data=["id", "y2"])

# pick points that are special...
df2 = df.iloc[np.unique(np.random.randint(0, len(df), 5))]

# add special markers without hoverinfo
fig.add_traces(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df2.index, y=df2["y1"], mode="markers", name="Ground Truth", hoverinfo="skip"
    )
)
```

[image]